# How to use a parallel std::for_each on systems where <execution> is missing?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17

This C++17 snippet works fine in newer versions of G++

```cpp
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, container.begin(), container.end(), [&](const auto& element) {
    // do something with element... or don't. whatever.
});
```

When you try to port that code to the current Debian (Stable) distribution for instance, which has G++ 8.3.0 (as of 12/2020), you'll find yourself reading the following error message:

```
fatal error: execution: File not found
     #include <execution>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

An obvious solution relying on `__has_include` that involves a macro is:

```cpp
#if __has_include(<execution>)
    #include <execution>
    #define PAR_UNSEQ std::execution::par_unseq,
#else
    #define PAR_UNSEQ
#endif

std::for_each(PAR_UNSEQ container.begin(), container.end(), [&](const auto& element) {
    // do something with element... or don't. whatever.
});
```

This compiles fine but has 2 major issues in my eyes:

- It is not a parallel for on systems, that don't have the `<execution>` header and
- that macro is not something I enjoy looking at.

So is there a better way?

Or if not is there at least a macro solution that actually does a parallel `for_each`?

Comment: In the case of `for_each()` you can use an OpenMP parallel for loop instead.

Comment: @Shawn Never tried OpenMP, since the STL has that functionality already, at least I thought so. Has that any pros/cons over the other answer?

Comment: It's widely supported by compilers and fairly portable, unlike C++17 parallel `for_each()` for (I suspect) at least another 5 years if not longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<execution>` was added in gcc 9 (9.1 I think) but you could use the underlying library, [Intel® oneAPI Threading Building Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/parallel_for.html) or `tbb` for short, directly instead. It's a little cumbersome but something like the below would work in gcc 8.3 if you link with `-ltbb` (which you need to link with even in the newer gcc versions where `<execution>` is included). My example uses [`tbb::parallel_for`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/parallel_for.html) which is what gcc:s `std::for_each` most likely also uses.

It solves, what I believe is, the most important part and that is that it's parallel on systems that don't have the `<execution>` header.

```
#if __has_include(<execution>)
    #include <execution>
#else
    #include "tbb/tbb.h"

    // define a support class for using with tbb::paralell_for
    template<typename C, typename Func>
    class ApplyFunc {
    public:
        ApplyFunc(const C& container, Func func) : c(container), f(func) {}

        // the function that will be called for each block
        void operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r) const {
            for(size_t i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i) 
                f(c[i]); // the function you'd like to apply to each element
        }

    private:
        const C& c;
        Func f;
    };
#endif

// A function to call std::for_each or the tbb version
template<typename C, typename Func>
decltype(auto) myfor_each(const C& container, Func func) {
    #if __has_include(<execution>)
        std::for_each(std::execution::par, container.begin(), container.end(), func);
    #else
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, container.size()),
                          ApplyFunc(container, func));
    #endif
}

int main() {
    // example usage
    std::vector<int> container;
    myfor_each(container, [](auto& e) { do something eith e });
}
```

Comment: This is really very clunky :/ The additional tbb linking and stuff and also `if` / `else` for each `for_each` ...

Comment: @nada I agree, but it's a way to make use of `tbb` without `<execution>`. You need to link with `tbb` to use `<exucution>` even in newer g++ versions too, so that's nothing extra. See the updated code for putting the calling of either version into a function.

Comment: Sorry for keeping nagging, but are you sure about the tbb linking? I don't link the Debian build any differently than the one which has `<execution>`...

Comment: @nada In that case, the debian version of gcc implicitly links with `tbb`. One way or another, it's `tbb` that's being used. Do `ldd your_binary | grep libtbb` and you'll see it.

Comment: The build where `<execution>` works is actually mingw64's G++ 10 point something. And I don't see anything tbb when I print ldd on my binary, too many others to post in a comment here. `libwinpthread-1.dll` looks like something to do with threads ^^. Could that be it?

Comment: @nada Ah... that could possibly be the Posix thread library `pthread` mashed together with `tbb` - or `tbb` is statically linked (and won't show up with `ldd`).

Comment: @nada If you don't have libtbb installed, libstdc++ silently falls back to the sequential version of the algorithm. If your program successfully links without -ltbb, I'm afraid it won't run in parallel. Well, at least when it comes to GCC10, but that behaviour has changed for 11: see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97549.

Comment: @nada That doesn’t make sense. Currently Intel’s pstl only supports the TBB backend and the sequential backend. So, if `ldd your_executable | grep tbb` returns nothing, it simply cannot run in parallel. On my linux system, where I have libtbb reachable through my LIBRARY_PATH, if I don’t link with -ltbb I get undefined TBB symbols. In contrast, I have an old laptop with Cygwin where there is no libtbb. I can use `par_unseq` there without linking TBB, but it doesn’t run in parallel.

Comment: @nada As I said, currently libstdc++ parallel algorithms need TBB to run in parallel. Alternate parallel backends are currently being developed. You can find more info in this thread: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/libcxx-dev/2020-September/000935.html.

Comment: @metalfox You were correct. My benchmark was bogus because I forgot to reload CMake (and actually link tbb by doing so) at some point. Tbb has to be linked against for <execution> to work parallel. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries that implement parallel algorithms that work on older compilers. The obvious one is the [Parallel STL](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/get-started-with-parallel-stl.html), which is what the GCC 9 implementation is based on. It has a TBB dependency.

Another options is [poolSTL](https://github.com/alugowski/poolSTL). It's a header-only implementation of some parallel C++17 algorithms, including `std::for_each`, without external dependencies. It works on older GCC and versions of Clang missing native support, and has a single-header version.

**Option 1:** use `poolstl::par` instead of `std::execution::par`:

```cpp
#include <poolstl/poolstl.hpp>


std::for_each(poolstl::par, container.begin(), container.end(), [&](const auto& element) {
    // do something with element... or don't. whatever.
});
```

**Option 2:** If you'd prefer to keep your code in terms of `std::execution` policies, there is a hacky mode where it can alias the poolSTL policies to the standard ones. It's basically a few `using` statements, but packaged up with some minor safeties (this is a hack!):

```cpp
#define POOLSTL_STD_SUPPLEMENT
#include <poolstl/poolstl.hpp>


std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, container.begin(), container.end(), [&](const auto& element) {
    // do something with element... or don't. whatever.
});
```